# interesting non-function relations

Tags: functions, relations

A function is defined as a binary relation between two sets that associates to each element of the first set exactly one element of the second set. While functions are obviously important in math, there seems to be at least some examples of mathematically interesting binary relations that do not meet criteria for being a function, for example a set of ordered pairs that form a circle in R^2, or the set of ordered pairs forming something like a limacon curve in polar coordinates.

My question is, what are some other examples of non-function relations in mathematics? And is there some sort of fancy name for these kinds of relations aside for "non-function relations"? Are non-function relations studied and characterized mathematically as systematically as functions are?

Comment: Yes. Big style. Google "reflexive symmetric transitive relations" for plenty of stuff.

Comment: General relations are widely studied. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations.